# Cookie not set with Reactjs + Node + Express + Nginx

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, express-session

I'm using Chrome (dev window) to check the cookie(s) but was not sent when my React app logged in in production(https). Read and tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564174/cookie-not-set-with-node-express-nginx) but still no cookie.

Node/express api app using express-session:

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(cors({origin: 'https://example.org', credentials: true}));
app.use(
    session({
        secret: SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        store: sessionStore,
        cookie: {
            secure: true,
            maxAge: oneDay
        },
    })
);
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name example-api.org; # managed by Certbot
  
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-api.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example-api.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_set_header Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
 }
```

React app hosted by Nginx and its config:

```
server {

    root /var/www/html/reactapp/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    server_name example.org; # managed by Certbot

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

React app uses axios:

```
const apiClientAppLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post<LoginFrontendAppResponse>(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login-client-app`,
      { password: process.env.REACT_APP_FRONTEND_PWD },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};
export { apiClientAppLogin };
```

Appreciate any help/tips!

Comment: Do you try save cookie in the server or send cookie from the client to the server?

Comment: No I did not try to save cookie in the server.  The sessionStore already store the 'cookie' in DB/mysql server.

I also did not send cookie from the client.  I thought by setting withCredentials: true will send the cookie to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Yanir and anyone interested to know, below is what works for me:

```
let sess = {
    secret: "...",
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {},
    store: sessionStore   // refer how to use express-session 1.17.3
}

const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'https://example.org'
    ],
    credentials: true
  })
);

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
sess.cookie.secure = true;
app.use(session(sess));
```

Strangely, (if you compare my previous post) by removing the followings it works:

```
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
```

I accepted for now but still wondering why. I guess I must dig further into the manual!